# How to calculate moving sums of rows of unique observation in R (example provided)?

Tags: r, sql-server, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` called `df` , and I am trying to count unique devices on a moving hour basis with a gap of 4 minutes as shown in `expected_df` . I have provided an example below . I did not find any query meeting my requirements , hence this ...

### Given data frame

```
df<-data.frame(customer=rep("xyz",19),
           device=c("a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","c","c","c","c","c","c","c"),
           local_date=rep("2020-06-04",19),
           local_hour=rep(4,19),
           local_minute=c(1:6,4:9,6:12))
```

### Expected data frame

```
expected_df<-data.frame(customer=rep("xyz",8),local_hour=rep(4,8),
                    local_date=rep("2020-06-04",8),
                    local_minute_bucket=c("1_5","2_6","3_7","4_9","5_9","6_10","7_11","8_12"),
                    unique_devices=c(2,3,3,3,3,3,2,2))
```

Comment: How are you calculating `unique_devices` ? How is the 1st value 2?

Comment: Because device a is tracked from 1:5 minute and device b from 4:5 , so unique count for 1_5 minutes is 2

Comment: Unless you your analysis will never include times that pass though midnight, I suggest supplying a date column.

Comment: Sure ...will add it ..

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach with `dplyr`, `lubridate` and `purrr`:

First, we create the time so that windows can cross hours and days. Second, we arrange by time so that `findInterval` can work. Next, we create a bucket. Then we use `findInterval` to calculate the rows that are within the bucket. Then, we use `map2` to find the unique devices in those rows.

We then deselect the appropriate columns and use `unique` to get rid of duplicates.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
df %>% 
  mutate(time = ymd_hm(paste0(local_date," ",local_hour,":",local_minute))) %>%
  arrange(time) %>%
  mutate(local_minute_bucket = paste0(minute(time),"_",minute(time+minutes(4))),
         unique_devices = map2_chr(row_number(time),
                                   findInterval(time + minutes(4),time),
                                   ~length(unique(device[.x:.y])))) %>%
  dplyr::select(-time,-device) %>%
  unique()
   customer local_date local_hour local_minute local_minute_bucket unique_devices
1       xyz 2020-06-04          4            1                 1_5              2
2       xyz 2020-06-04          4            2                 2_6              3
3       xyz 2020-06-04          4            3                 3_7              3
4       xyz 2020-06-04          4            4                 4_8              3
6       xyz 2020-06-04          4            5                 5_9              3
8       xyz 2020-06-04          4            6                6_10              3
9       xyz 2020-06-04          4            6                6_10              2
11      xyz 2020-06-04          4            7                7_11              2
13      xyz 2020-06-04          4            8                8_12              2
15      xyz 2020-06-04          4            9                9_13              2
16      xyz 2020-06-04          4            9                9_13              1
17      xyz 2020-06-04          4           10               10_14              1
18      xyz 2020-06-04          4           11               11_15              1
19      xyz 2020-06-04          4           12               12_16              1
```

Comment: For  9_13 , you have 2 different values like 2 & 1 ....it has to be only 1 value for one bucket

Answer (score 1):

here is a `data.table` approach

```
#create an data.table with intervals
library( data.table )
library( lubridate )

#make df a data.table
setDT( df )
#create a proper timestamp
df[, timestamp := as.POSIXct( paste0( local_date, "T", local_hour, ":", local_minute ),
                              format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M" )]
#crete a data.table with intervals
dt.intervals <- data.table( start = seq( min( df$timestamp, na.rm = TRUE ),
                                         max( df$timestamp, na.rm = TRUE ),
                                         by = "1 min" ) )
dt.intervals[, end := start %m+% minutes(4)]
dt.intervals[, local_minute_bucket := paste( format( start, "%M"), format( end, "%M"), sep = "_" )]
#join
ans <- dt.intervals[ df, on = .( start <= timestamp, end >= timestamp ), allow.cartesian = TRUE ]
#and summarise
ans[, .(unique_devides = uniqueN( device )), by = .(customer, local_hour, local_date, local_minute_bucket )]


#    customer local_hour local_date local_minute_bucket unique_devides
# 1:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               01_05              2
# 2:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               02_06              3
# 3:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               03_07              3
# 4:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               04_08              3
# 5:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               05_09              3
# 6:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               06_10              3
# 7:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               07_11              2
# 8:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               08_12              2
# 9:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               09_13              2
#10:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               10_14              1
#11:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               11_15              1
#12:      xyz          4 2020-06-04               12_16              1
```

Answer (score 1):

Can't come up with anything better than this.

A function which gives the data for a particular time interval.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

Get_data <- function(data, minute) {

  data %>%
    filter(local_minute >= minute & local_minute <= minute + 4) %>%
    summarise(local_minute_bucket = paste(min(local_minute), 
                                          max(local_minute), sep = '-'), 
              unique_devices = n_distinct(device))
}
```

Split the data based for every date and hour and apply this function for every minute till `max - 4` minute.

```
df %>%
  group_split(local_date, local_hour) %>%
  map_df(function(data) data %>% 
                          group_by(local_date, local_hour) %>%
                          summarise(new = list(map(seq_len(max(local_minute) - 4),
                                    Get_data, data = data)))) %>%
   unnest(new) %>%
   unnest_wider(new)


#  local_date local_hour local_minute_bucket unique_devices
#  <chr>           <dbl> <chr>                        <int>
#1 2020-06-04          4 1-5                              2
#2 2020-06-04          4 2-6                              3
#3 2020-06-04          4 3-7                              3
#4 2020-06-04          4 4-8                              3
#5 2020-06-04          4 5-9                              3
#6 2020-06-04          4 6-10                             3
#7 2020-06-04          4 7-11                             2
#8 2020-06-04          4 8-12                             2
```

Comment: I thought of something like this too, but it won't work for bins that cross dates or hours... unfortunately.

Comment: I am not sure how OP wants output when hours cross but my answer would keep hours separate and they'll not crossover.

Comment: Thanks for the solution , but my example did not cover all permutation & combinations ... For example when hour or date changes , then rolling 3 minute window also changes like 4:59 pm to 5:02 or 2020-05-31 23:59 to 2020-06-01 00:02 .....  At any given time of the day , I want to calculate # devices within last 4 minutes at each minute of the day continuously ..... Apologies for my example did not capture all such cases !